# CSS not being applied from site.css

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with this part of my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zion Hill</title>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="login-block">
        <div class="toggle-item">Login</div>
        <div class="popup-form">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in this file *css/site.css* I have:

```
#login-block {
    background-color: rgb(143, 181, 240);
    float: left;
}

    #login-block .toggle-item {
        text-align: left;
    }

    #login-block .popup-form {
        display: none;
        background-color: grey;
        border: solid 1px black;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

Why is the style not being applied and the user agent style is being used?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the stylesheet is loading in the Network tab of the developer tools? Maybe the path to the css file is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem i can figure out from what you provided, is that this path "**css/site.css**" could be incorrect. Make sure that index file is in the same directory as "**css**" folder and that "**css**" folder contains "**site.css**" file

Answer (score 0):

When I duplicated your html and css, it works. Therefore, the path href=**"css/site.css"** must be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The above link file path could be incorrect. endeavour your project files `site.css` and `index.html` file and in the same folder. And should be place inside the `head` tag

#### Example

`link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">`